# Why use magic number in the implementation of regex in java?

Tags: java, regex, magic-numbers

The source code of constructor of Matcher class:

```
Matcher(Pattern parent, CharSequence text) {
    this.parentPattern = parent;
    this.text = text;

    // Allocate state storage
    int parentGroupCount = Math.max(parent.capturingGroupCount, 10);
    groups = new int[parentGroupCount * 2];
    locals = new int[parent.localCount];

    // Put fields into initial states
    reset();
}
```

Why we don't just use parent.capturingGroupCount*2 as the length of groups?

Comment: It's probably so you can use `\0` - `\9` without anything failing.

Comment: @gabe make that comment an answer

Comment: If he doesn't, I will :)

Comment: @Gabe You mean someone may use \9, but actually the regex doesn't contain the 9th group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably to make it easier to support backreferences (`\0`-`\9`) without having any special cases.